# Unexpected result when two threads accessing a global variable

Tags: c#, multithreading, locking, global-variables

I have two threads, t1 and t2.
They both do add operation on a global variable named 'count', which was initialized with 0.
t1 does `count++` and t2 does `count+=100`. I start t1 first then t2, but the output result doesn't meet my expectation.
Is there I misunderstand something?

It won't help even though I used lock() in two threads.

Here's the C# code:

```
private int count = 0;
private object locker = new object();

void run()
{
    var t1 = new Thread(Add_1);
    var t2 = new Thread(Add_2);
    t1.Start();
    t2.Start();
}
```

```
void Add_1()
{
    lock(locker)
    {
        count++;
        Console.WriteLine(count);
    }
}

void Add_2()
{
    lock(locker)
    {
        count += 100;
        Console.WriteLine(count);
    }
}
```

It sometimes prints

> 1
>   101

or

> 100
>   101

I don't have any idea of that. In my opinion, t1 should have the locker until it finished its job. But it seems that t2 has chance to add count earlier than t1.

Hope someone can give me a hand, thanks.

Comment: Just because you're starting threads in that order, it doesn't mean that the first-started thread will be the "winner" to the lock condition.

Comment: All a `lock` guarantees is that two threads won't enter a block of code locked by a given lock (`locker`) at the same time. So in that respect, both results are correct.

Comment: `Is there I misunderstand something?` - Yes; That is not unexpected result, it is exactly the expected result if you want to use different threads. Or at least it should be the expected result if you understand what threads are and what they are for. Your expectation would be sequential, not asynchronous...

Comment: What are your expectations ?

Comment: @John Really appreciate your detailed reply. It helps a lot for me.

Comment: @user1810087 Yes, my expectation was sequential.

Comment: @DmytroMukalov My scenario was, job1 modified count then job2 uses the modified count in its job.

Comment: @user1810087 Yes, my expectation was sequential.

Answer (score 1):

What's wrong? Actually, the order you define, or start, in your code, doesn't tell your computer how to execute. In fact, you have two completely separated threads and your VM/Processor can execute it in any order. A lock don't tell it what's the correct execution order, but only that one Thread is in, other threads have to wait.

So, your program works fine. If you want to execute it in an order, you don't need threads, or you can use any async/await method to sync them, or you can put one to sleep.

Maybe, you want to take a look at these articles

- https://www.tutorialspoint.com/csharp/csharp_multithreading.htm
- https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/26130/Threads-and-Thread-Synchronization-in-C
- http://www.albahari.com/threading/
- https://www.codingame.com/playgrounds/4240/your-ultimate-async-await-tutorial-in-c/introduction